# How do I stream data from Snowflake SQLs to S3? using Kafka or other services

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

We have a COPY statement today which we use to run SQL on Snowflake Warehouse and download the data to our S3 bucket using Snowflake's External Stage and Storage Integration objects.

Now, I would like to build an automated pipeline whereby any new records fetched by the COPY statement should automatically write this data to our S3 bucket using the same External State and Storage Integration objects.

I read from this link below that we can stream the data from Kafka to Snowflake. Can we do the same but the other way around, i.e. from Snowflake to Kafka to S3.

https://community.snowflake.com/s/article/How-To-Streaming-From-Kafka-to-Snowflake-Part-2-S3-to-Snowflake-with-Snowpipe

Answer (score 0):

Snowpipe is a "AWS Lamda" like process the monitors the "external file store" and on file arrival runs "ingestion code".

The inverse is something that "watching your tables for insert/updates/deletes" and writes that delta information to a bucket.

But lets step back, when do "things write to your tables" = "when you insert more data" so what process are you using "to write more", and why not have that "write to the external store". If the new data was external data, and if internal data, if there is no new external data, how is you data changing?

Unless you are using someone else's shared data, and you are wanted to export that data. Which sounds fishy, but then you would most likely have to poll the shared data.

Another method is to push the data to a [external function](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/external-functions.html) request, thus you could use the end-point to enqueue the new data, and batch/stream it that one.